# PDO query to display on id information

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following table:

```
tbl_users
==============
id
username
password
email
```

I have the following code to get all the id's of the users and i only want to display the id field. But i can't get it to work.

```
$db = $DB_con;

 $stmt =  $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users");
          $result = $stmt->execute();

while ($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  echo $row['id'];
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in
```

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump($row)` inside your loop?

Comment: nothing, your right? but if run that sql statement directly on the db it gives me results fine

Comment: Are you checking for connection errors? Your error checking seems non-existent. Look in the error logs.

Comment: @BradHazelnut - well, if you're using `var_dump` inside the loop and seeing nothing, it suggests that your code isn't going into the loop at all - are you certain that the notice is being generated by the code you've included here? Are you referencing `id` elsewhere in your code?

Comment: `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and `foreach($result as $row => $key)` or something like that. Note: fetchAll returns numeric row array that consists of an associative array of column names => value

Comment: Here's something weird i just noticed if i take the statement "$row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)" and don't put it in the loop and do a var_dump on it it gives me the full array

Comment: Ah! You're using `fetchAll`; that loads all the results into a single array. If you want to iterate through the results one at a time, try `fetch` instead. Otherwise, use @Isaiah's suggestion to go through each item in your array,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns *all* of the rows. So you shouldn't call it inside a loop.

You can solve that in different ways. Here is one:

```
// Get the entire dataset
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

// Loop through the array
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
  echo $row['id'];
}
```

Another way (the one you intended to write), is to fetch the rows one by one using `fetch` instead of `fetchAll`:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  echo $row['id'];
}
```

By the way, if you're going to need only the `id`, it's best practise to only `select id from yourtable` instead of selecting everything using `*`. It will make the query (and thus your page) faster, and decrease the load on the database.

Comment: $result is a boolean when you write `$result = $stmt->execute();` The asker wrote that. @GolezTrol

Comment: @Isaiah Thanks for the feedback. Where did I write that?

Comment: You didn't, but the asker did and you didn't mention that @GolezTrol

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `foreach` to loop through the results.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( "SELECT id FROM tbl_users;" );
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
foreach ($result as $row => $value) {
  echo $value['id'];
}
```

Note: fetchAll returns a multidimenional array. Therefore, outside a foreach loop, you would use `$result[$row_number][$column_name]` to access values.

Also, `$stmt->execute()` returns a boolean indicating the success of the query, NOT the result set.